# Running Photoshop scripts from PHP?

Tags: php, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm creating a web service which revolves around users creating custom image files from details they enter on the webpage. I have the PSD files completed, along with the accompanying scripts, but how can I launch the Photoshop scripts directly from my PHP code?

I looked into using Droplets, but from what I can see I can only use these to perform recorded actions on a file.

Comment: Please provide some code of what you have tried so the question is easier to understand.

Comment: I don't know how I can phrase it any simpler. There is no code, because I'm asking how I can accomplish it. The PHP script makes edits to the Photoshop Script (.jsx), which when run against the matching PSD will make all the edits as specified by the user. There doesn't seem to be a way to launch the both of them from the command line or the like, so how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how Photoshop script works. Do you mean you want to open a file with PHP?

Comment: I want to use a Photoshop Script to commit changes to a Photoshop .PSD  file. I know it can be done, I'm just at a loss of how to do it.

Comment: Hi, have you got solution, if yes please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sort of possible, but you'll need to provide more details about what you wish to accomplish. Would this server be a mac or windows? Something that was capable ofrunning Photoshop.

Here's an inline example of executing a PS script with Photoshop from PHP on a mac within Terminal.

```
$ php -r "`open -b \"com.adobe.Photoshop\" myPhotoshopScript.jsx`;"
```

Or better yet, use the [Symfony Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) and [Filesystem](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html) components to manage this.

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;

$fs = new Filesystem();

$photoshopProcessBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
$photoshopProcessBuilder->setPrefix('open -b "com.adobe.Photoshop"');

if ($fs->exists($photoshopScriptFile)) {

    $photoshopProcessBuilder->setArguments(array($photoshopScriptFile));

    $photoshopScriptRunnerProcess = $photoshopProcessBuilder->getProcess();
    $photoshopScriptRunnerProcess->run();

    if (!$photoshopScriptRunnerProcess->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException($photoshopScriptRunnerProcess->getErrorOutput());
    }

    // do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The server in question is Windows, and the Symfony approach does look like a much nicer way to do it. I'm on my cell and can't look, but does Symfony have a library for accessing COM objects? If I could access Photoshop's COM API to stop the actual GUI from launching on the server it'd be perfect.

Comment: @pablo Cool, I'd need to also experiment how to do it on Windows, should be very similar. What's the COM API? I've never heard of this. :)

Comment: http://cssdk.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/csawlib/com/adobe/photoshop/package-detail.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way it can be done is to record an action loading the script and create a Droplet out of the action, then execute it from PHP passing the PSD as a parameter. It's not as elegant as I wanted, but there doesn't seem to be any other suggestions.